# Protected characters in a shell function

Tags: shell, zsh

Many years ago, I wrote a shell function to search text string within PDF files. Like, I was in a directory with hundreds or thousands of PDF files, and call this function to search a particular phrase. This is the function

```
function pdfsearch() {
    local searchStr=${1:?"The string to search must be the argument"}
    find . -iname "*.pdf" | while read fname
    do
        pdftotext -q -enc ASCII7 "$fname" ".$fname~"; grep -s -H --color=always -i $searchStr ".fname~"
        rm ".fname~"
    done
}
```

Although ugly, this works fine. The encoding bit of the `pdftotext` was to remove the character ligatures of certain documents (the double f in stuff was being interpreted like the single character "ﬀ").

Now, I'm trying to modify, so it search only in certain pdf, based on the filename. So it takes an extra argument. My attempt was this

```
function pdfsearch() {
    local searchStr=${1:?"The string to search must be the argument"}
    local fileStr=${2:-"*.pdf"}
    find . -iname $fileStr | while read fname
    do
        pdftotext -q -enc ASCII7 "$fname" ".$fname~"; grep -s -H --color=always -i $searchStr ".fname~"
        rm ".fname~"
    done
}
```

However, this does not work. I always get

```
pdfsearch:3 *.pdf not found
```

With the `*.pdf` substituted with whatever I pass as 2nd argument.

I believe the problem is the quotes I'm putting within `fileStr`. I tried with single quotes, protecting them with `\` and putting `"$fileStr"`.

I'm almost sure this is pretty basic character expansion syntax. Also, in case it matters, I'm using zsh as my shell. I used to put this function on my `.bashrc` and it's now on my `.zshrc`

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how `pdftotext` will know to add a `$` to `-i searchStr`, which I would do as `-i "$searchStr"` . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. And the ``-i $searchStr`` is actually for ``grep``, not ``pdftotext``

Comment: *"... is actually for grep"*. Well then I'm surprise again, as to your use of `..."$fname" ".$fname~", grep ...` (using a `,` char). Don't you want `..."$fname" ".$fname~" | grep ...` (using the *pipe* (`|`) char)? I had assumed that `pdftotext` had some fancy optionality separated by `,`s.  Have you checked your code at https://shellcheck.net ?

Comment: In addition to my answer below I'll second what @shellter points out. Your use of a comma to separate the two commands is invalid. You should be using a semi-colon or, better, putting the two commands on separate lines. I ignored that aspect of your code in my solution because I assumed the comma was a typo. Which is why you should always copy/paste your code rather than re-type it.

Comment: And that's another typo. My xterm was iffy with the copy so I typed that line, and indeed, is invalid. It is actualy a ``;``, not a ``,``. Apologies for the syntax errors

Comment: Agreed, please copy/paste! (you will learn (-;!)  ALSO as you're along the way in shell programming, you need to learn what debugging tools are available. Add `set -x` near the top of the script. (`set +x` will turn it of). You will see  the actual line the shell has assembled to execute (all env-vars, cmd-substitions, etc performed) preceded by `+` char. Also,  `export PS4='+ ${LINENO} >'` will show you what line number is being executed. Good luck.

Comment: shelter, could you please post one of your comments as a answer? I found the error thatnks to your comment and reccomendation of shellcheck. That way I can mark it as the proper answer. I posted the fixed code as an answer as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the comments. I used the https://www.shellcheck.net/ tool as recommended, and found a couple of things to fix.

Also, in my actual code there was a space that should not have been there. I didn't put in the question cause I thought it was non relevant, but it turns out, it is. The code I was trying to run was

```
function pdfsearch() {
    local searchStr=${1:?"The string to search must be the argument"}
    local fileStr  =${2:-"*.pdf"}
    find . -iname $fileStr | while read fname
    do
        pdftotext -q -enc ASCII7 "$fname" ".$fname~"; grep -s -H --color=always -i $searchStr ".fname~"
        rm ".fname~"
    done
}
```

Apparently, I tried to align the `=` for some reason.

The fixed version:

```
function pdfsearch() {
    local searchStr=${1:?"The string to search must be the argument"}
    local fileStr=${2:-"*.pdf"}
    find . -iname "$fileStr" | while read -r fname
    do
        pdftotext -q -enc ASCII7 "$fname" ".$fname~"; grep -s -H --color=always -i "$searchStr" ".fname~"
        rm ".fname~"
    done
}
```

And this one works as intended

Comment: That the spaces before the equal sign caused a problem is another reason to avoid POSIX shells, like Bash and Zsh, like the plague and instead use a modern sane shell like Elvish or Fish. I also hope you learned how important it is to accurately report what you tried. That is, copy/paste your actual code rather than type what you think you ran.

Comment: A `=` sign in front of a word causes the shell to search an executable of this name in the PATH, and expand the expression to the full path of the executable. Try for instance `echo =ls`.

Comment: @shellter: You looked at the wrong shells. As you see, the question is tagged with _zsh_, and when I mention "the shell" in this context, I mean of course zsh, and not bash or ksh or whatever. Admittedly, the documentation for the `=`-expansion needs some digging to be found,. Read _man zshexpn_, and search the (pretty lengthy) chapter titled _FILENAME EXPANSION_.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX shell behavior regarding variable expansion is awful. I strongly recommend switching to a modern, sane, shell like Fish or Elvish. Having said that, your problem is the unquoted `$fileStr` in `find . -iname $fileStr | while read fname`. The shell is replacing `$fileStr` with its value: `*.pdf`, then attempting to expand the glob before running the `find` command. Since you don't have any files with a `pdf` extension in the CWD the glob expansion fails with the error you're seeing. Had the glob expanded to two or more files you would get a different error:

```
bash> touch x.pdf y.pdf
bash> x='*.pdf'
bash> find . -iname $x
find: y.pdf: unknown primary or operator
```

The solution is to quote the variable expansion:

```
bash> find . -iname "$x"
./x.pdf
./y.pdf
```

In fact, you should almost always double-quote variable expansion in POSIX shells.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the quoted ``"$fileStr"`` makes no difference. Still getting the ``not found`` error message, which I believe now comes from ``pdftotext``, not the find command

Comment: Then you aren't doing what you wrote in your question. In fact, given your use of a comma to separate the `pdftotext` and `grep` commands in your question I am certain you are not accurately telling us what you are doing. What happens if you do `x='*.pdf`; find . -iname "*.pdf"`? The original error message in your question makes it very clear the "not found" is from the glob expansion in the `find` command. Now you're saying you "think" the error is from `pdftotext`.

Comment: That was another typo. I apologize for that. And thank you for your input. There is a ; before the grep, not a comma. I tested with a simple ``echo "$fname"`` instead of the long command, and I'm still getting the not found error. But cant reproduce it from the ``find`` alone

Comment: Sigh! If you replaced the compound `pdftotext ...; grep ...` line with a simple `echo "$fname"` and still got a "not found" error then you are still not accurately reporting what you are doing. @phollox

Comment: Your explanation would be correct for POSIX shells indeed, but the OP is using zsh. In this case, quoting the variable is pointless, since word splitting happens after parameter expansion. If you try in zsh `x='*'; echo $x`, you will see that you get a literal `*` printed.

Comment: @user1934428 You missed the point of my previous feedback. The POSIX semantics are horrible and the fact that Bash and Zsh disagree on how they handle this variable expansion is why pseudo POSIX behavior should be avoided if at all possible. Most people expect Bash and Zsh (and Ksh) to behave identically with respect to this question.

Comment: Just my personal opinion: If you follow this line of thinking, you would attempt to write code which works the same in bash and zsh (and maybe even in ksh or sh). The common subset is so small that you can use it for only pretty simple scripts. I once had the idea to write a file to be sourced at startup from bash and zsh, so I have only one common code with all my functions etc., no matter which shell I was using. It turned out to be a nightmare for writing and for debugging.

Comment: Whatever "most people" may think, it's already painful enough to write code which is compatible across several version of a single language (bash 3 vs. bash 5, Python 2 vs. Python 3, ....), and in addition trying to be compatible between different languages can drive you mad; in particular since zsh explicitly says in its man page that it does not attempt to be POSIX, unless it is explicitly run in POSIX mode. You have to _request_ compatibility if you want your zsh script to be at least somewhat POSIX.

Comment: @KurtisRader, Thanks for pointing out the POSIX shell behaviour. Indeed, I expected bash and zsh to behave similarly. I've seen instances where they don't, but was not aware that there were that many. I started using bash because it was the default on my first distro. and switched recently to zsh because the autocomplete features seemed cool. I wouldn't mind trying something else.